# How can I get Keychain Access back

Tags: macos

I bought a used Mac air with Catalina, being a newbie to apple computers I somehow corrupted Keychain Access.  I am unable to delete what is left of it, the folder in the library is also missing, I have tried resetting but it does not work.  What or how should I do to regain a new Keychain Access?  Thanks much.

FTR

Comment: Hi Gloria - Welcome to SO. This is a forum for programming questions. If you have a general OS type question you'll have better luck on https://superuser.com.  Copy/paste your question there and you should find some help.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that.